# Can we retrieve the requestor details through a SOAP call using Apache CXF?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

We are getting a SOAP request on our server from various systems. Before sending the response , we need to make some new requests to the requesting system to fetch some details. To do so, we need to determine the details of the requesting server. Is there a way to detemine:
 - Requesting System VIP
 - Requestor IP
 - Other requestor specific details

Comment: You use JAX-WS for your Web Service provider?

Comment: ok, so I will keep my answer just for reference.

Comment: just realized that CXF implements the JAX-WS API, so my answer may be a solution - depends on your implementation. BTW: I slightly modified your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JAX-WS API, you can use [`WebServiceContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html) to retrieve message meta-data. Just inject a reference into your implementation:

```
@WebService(name = "MyService" /*...*/)
public class MyService {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext wsc;

    @WebMethod
    public MyResponse process(MyRequest request) {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) wsc.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);

        httpRequest.getRemoteAddr(); // access some parameters...

        return new MyResponse();
    }

}
```

It allows you to access 'everything' that came along via the HTTP request like caller address.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Soap service is based on Http protocol. You can use [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)'s getRemote...() methods. But I am not sure whether that information will be enough for you. Another option would be to ask the client to include the client information that you need in their requests.